# Approximation of an integral with the Gamma function

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Let $\Gamma$ denote the usual [Gamma function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

I'd like to have an approximation of
${\displaystyle f(x):=\int_{2}^{+\infty}x^{\Gamma(t)}dt}$ when $x \nearrow 1$.

I think I can show that $f(x)=o((1-x)^a)$ pour all $a<0$, but I'd rather have a "simple" function equal to $f$ asymptotically when $x \nearrow 1$.

Comment: $$x^{\Gamma(t)}\sim e^{\sqrt{2\pi /t}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^{t}\,\log(x)}$$as $t\to \infty$

Comment: interesting question (+1)

Comment: a good approximation to the integral $I(\delta)=\int_2^{\infty}e^{-\delta\Gamma(x)}$ is given by $$I(\delta)\approx x^*(\delta)-2$$ where $x^*$ is determined by the unique positive solution with $x>1$ to the equation $\Gamma(x)=1/\delta$. The reason is that the integrand converges to something like $\chi_{0,x^*}(x)$ in the limit $\delta\rightarrow 0$. Maybe this gives someone inspiration for a rigorous answer (i am too busy to try....). Note also that the $2$ in the integration range can be replaced by any constant of order unity...